# Why the main thread is not terminated

Tags: java, threadpool, program-entry-point, executorservice

As far as I know, the uncaught thread will terminate with the current thread.
In the following code, the main method has been executed, but why is it not terminated?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    executorService.execute(() -> {
        while (true) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So you run this program and it never stops running?

Comment: @SamOrozco Yes, you can practice it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your runtime exception happens in the ExecutorService thread pool.  It catches and  swallows the exception and the thread keeps running.
The application will keep running while there is at least one non-daemon thread running.  You have 2 of them running (in the pool).
Now if before leaving the main thread you call executorService.shutdown(), then it will finish running all your tasks and then application will exit.

Comment: The essence of this problem is the daemon thread and the non-daemon thread. I will go to understand them, thank you for your answer.